# How can I properly solve the Black Scholes PDE numerically?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, programming, error-propagation

I have a problem numerically solving the following PDE with boundary conditions:
$$
u_t + \frac{x^2\sigma^2}2u_{xx} + rxu_x - ru = 0 \quad (x,t) \in (0,N) \times (0,T)
$$
with
$$
u(x,T) = \max\{0,x-K\}˛ \quad u(0,t) = 0, \quad u(N,t) = N - K.
$$
(This is the Black Scholes PDE to determine the fair price of an European call option.) Originally $x$ should vary over $\mathbb{R}^+$. However to numerically solve the problem, I should choose $N$ sufficiently large. The given parameters are $K = 12, r = 0.04, \sigma = 0.4$ and $T = 2$. I am supposed to use the explicit Euler method.

First, I discretise the underlying space using $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, I define $x_i = h i$ and $t_j = \tau j$ with $h = \frac Nn, \tau = \frac Tm$ and $i \in \{0,\dots,n\}, j \in \{0,\dots,m\}$. I use the recursion, using $u_i^j := u(x_i,t_j)$,
$$
\frac1\tau(u_i^j - u_i^{j-1}) + \frac{x_i^2\sigma^2}2\frac1{h^2}(u_{i+1}^{j} - 2u_{i}^{j} + u_{i-1}^{j}) + rx_i \frac1{2h}(u_{i+1}^{j} - u_{i-1}^{j}) - r u_{i}^{j-1} = 0.
$$ (Notice that I use $w_i^{j-1}$ as the last term and not $w_i^j$). Rearranging, I get
the recursion
$$
w_i^{j-1} = \frac1{1+r\tau}\left(u_i^j + \frac{x_i^2\sigma^2}2\frac{\tau}{h^2}(u_{i+1}^{j} - 2u_{i}^{j} + u_{i-1}^{j}) + rx_i \frac{\tau}{2h}(u_{i+1}^{j} - u_{i-1}^{j})\right).
$$
Translating my boundary conditions yields
$$
w_0^j = 0, \quad w_n^j = N - K, \quad w_i^m = \max\{0, x_i - K\}.
$$

**Now my Problem**
When implementing this procedure (using R) (I use e.g. $N = 30$, $m = 5000$ and $n = 200$), I get a really unstable behaviour.

Here you can see 3 pictures, where you can see the (in that order) time steps $t_j$ for $j = 2962, 2959, 2956$
[image]

[image]

[image]

The solution seems to oscillate more and more and I am not exactly sure why. Maybe just due to numerical errors? This behaviour gets worse when I consider even smaller $t_j$, up until a point where it is unrecognisable.

For $n = 100$ the solutions looks fine, with no unstable behaviour at all. I would suspect that I get more errors when $n$ is too small, but here it is the other way around.

Unfortunately I have basically no experience for numerically solving a PDE and am not sure what I can try next and why I see this behaviour.

If you need more information (code, etc.) let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $5000$ time steps in $2$ years seems a lot. How does it look like when you use a less drastic number? Say, $1000$ ?

Comment: The problem remains, and I already experimented with a bunch of different values for $N$ and $m$. Whenever $n$ is 'too big', the weird oscillating behaviour remains. Additionally should't the approximation actually converge to the real solution when $m$ and $n$ are large?

Comment: In theory yes *but* our calculators have limited precision and rounding errors can be amplified. Another idea: your BS model allows to calculate the probability that $x$ is above the boundary $N\,.$ You should choose $N$ s.t. this probability is practically zero.

Comment: There seems two typos: the term $u_{i+1}^{j} - 2u_{i}^{j} + u_{i+1}^{j}$ should be $u_{i+1}^{j} - 2u_{i}^{j} + u_{i\color{red}{-}1}^{j}\,.$

Comment: Ok, I tried varying $N$ up until 10000 (changing $n$ and $m$ also). However the results are the same. Whenever $n$ is beyond 100 the whole thing fails. Thanks, but the Typo just is in the LaTeX code and not in the actual code. (I corrected it above)

Comment: Would you be able to share the R code for these plots? Also, how did you derive the time steps t_j for j=2962,2959,2956?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

Sorry, I just realise that the smooth graph below was obtained with a vol
of
$$
\sigma=0.2
$$
instead of your $\sigma=0.4\,.$ So it seems that the large vol is
the reason for the instability, not the space step/time step configuration
which seems totally OK. (end of edit)

I have experimented with a bit of python code myself and also consulted the classic book P. Willmot, S. Howison, J. Dewynne, *The Mathematics of Financial Derivatives* (1995). The authors write on p. 143 that an explicit scheme (yours) is stable if and only if (in your notation)
$$
0< \alpha:=\frac{\tau}{h^2}=\frac{T\,n^2}{N^2\,m}\le \frac{1}{2}\,.
$$
In other words, when you have a stable configuration and double the number of space steps $n$ you have to ***quadruple*** the number $m$ of time steps to keep stability.

In your example we have $N=30,T=2,n=200,m=5000$ which gives
$$
\alpha=0.01777
$$
which should give a stable result, and indeed I am getting a smooth graph
which agrees very well with the closed form BS solution,
unless the underlying is far ITM:

[image]

- With $\sigma=0.2$ that I used the probability that the underlying is above $N=30$ in two years when it is at $13$ today is
  $$
  \mathbb P(X_T>N)\approx 0.06\%
  $$
  which is I think small enough. With your $\sigma=0.4$ this would be $2\%$ which I think is too large. Then also, my code fails.
- I believe that the discrepancy of the graphs near $N=30$ shows that
  for large vols you have to take a far larger $N$ and ensure again
  that the stability parameter $\alpha$ is small.

Code:

```
from numpy import log, exp, sqrt, linspace
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def option( S, K, T, r, sig, eps ):
    d1 = eps*(log(S/K) + r*T + sig**2*T/2)/sig/sqrt(T)
    d2 = eps*(log(S/K) + r*T - sig**2*T/2)/sig/sqrt(T)
    Nd1 = norm.cdf(d1)
    Nd2 = norm.cdf(d2)
    return( eps*S*Nd1 - eps*exp(-r*T)*K*Nd2 )  
r = 0.04 
K = 13  
sig = 0.2
T = 2
N = 30
n = 200
m = 5000
h = N/n
tau = T/m
alpha = tau/h**2
print( "alpha  {:10.6f}".format( alpha ) )
d2 = (log(K/N) - sig**2*T)/sig/sqrt(T)
print( "P(S>N) {:10.6f}".format( norm.cdf(d2) ) )
X = linspace(0.001,N,n)  
U = linspace(0,N,n)
W = linspace(0,N,n)
for i in range(n):
    U[i] = max( X[i]-K, 0 )
t = T
while( t > tau+1e-6 ):
   t -= tau
   for i in range(1,n-1):
       df = 1/(1+tau*r)
       D2 = (X[i]*sig)**2*tau*(U[i+1] - 2*U[i] + U[i-1])/2/h**2
       W[i] = df*( U[i] + D2 + r*X[i]*tau*(U[i+1]-U[i-1])/2/h )
   for i in range(1,n-1):
       U[i] = W[i]
O = linspace(0,N,n)
for i in range(n):
    O[i] = option( X[i], K, T, r, sig, 1 )
plt.plot( X, U, label="PDE" )
plt.plot( X, O, label="BS" )
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I tried implementing it in python as well, to see if R was somehow the problem. However, I still seem to get the same errors. If n is beyond 100, the whole thing fails towards the end. Would you mind, sharing your python code (only the important part involving the recursion)?

Comment: @julian2000P Done. What results do you get with $\sigma=0.2\,?$

Comment: @julian2000P I think the way we are trying to handle this is not optimal. For large $\sigma$ the term `(X[i]*sig)**2` which corresponds to $\sigma^2S^2$ aka $\sigma^2x^2$ in the PDE is problematic. You are probably better off when you do the classic [BS variable transformation](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/50820/why-do-we-perform-change-of-variable-for-black-scholes-equation) to get rid of this $S^2$ aka $x^2\,.$

Comment: Thanks for the code! Yes, the $\sigma$ term seems to be the problem. When I make $\sigma$ smaller (like 0.2) then $n$ can be made bigger, without any problems. Thanks, I will try a logarithmic variable transformation and see if I can get a more stable solution.

Comment: I tried using a logarithmic transformation, to transform the Black Scholes PDE into the heat equation which gave me a satisfying (and much more stable) results. Thanks again! I am accepting your answer from above.